# zsh: command not found: php. PHP is installed and working with MAMP

Tags: php, composer-php, zsh

I am trying to use composer to install a google client library, but cannot install composer or use php on the command line.

I am using php 8.0.8 with MAMP and it is working fine, so I know it is installed.
If I type php in the terminal, I receive the command not found message. Thinking it could be an environment variable, I have tried navigating to the php folder /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.8/lib/php and tried the php command again, but still get the same error

I am using a Mac running Monterey

Comment: You need to add PHP to your PATH. Here is a link that shows you how: https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/5987693

Comment: If you type a command just by its name, it is relevant to where your working directory is, unless you have relative pathes in your `path` array (which is not recommended anyway). Can you run PHP by providing it's absolute path?

Comment: @Wimanicesir - thank for this. All working. If you add it as an answer I will select.

Comment: If PHP itself is not running, what have you tried to resolve that? Is this even related to Composer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Change default Mac OS X PHP to MAMP's PHP Installation and Install Composer Package Management

---

#### Instructions to Change PHP Installation

---

First, Lets find out what version of PHP we're running (To find out if it's the default version).

To do that, Within the terminal, Fire this command:

```
which php
```

This should output the path to the default PHP install which comes preinstalled by Mac OS X, by default it has to be (Assuming you've not changed it before):

```
/usr/bin/php
```

Now, We just need to swap this over to the PHP that is installed with MAMP, which is located at `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin` (MAMP 2.1.3)

To do this, We need to edit the `.bash_profile` and add the MAMP version of PHP to the PATH variable.

##### Follow these simple steps:

---

1. Within the Terminal, run `vim ~/.bash_profile`
2. Type `i` and then paste the following at the top of the file:

   ```
    export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin:$PATH
   ```
3. Hit `ESC`, Type `:wq`, and hit `Enter`
4. In Terminal, run `source ~/.bash_profile`
5. In Terminal, type in `which php` again and look for the updated string. If everything was successful, It should output the new path to MAMP PHP install.
6. In case it doesn't output the correct path, try closing the terminal window (exit fully) and open again, it should apply the changes (Restart in short).

#### Install Composer Package Management

---

Now you can fire the command to install the composer globally (So you can access it from anywhere):

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

You can verify your installation worked by typing the following command within the Terminal:

```
composer
```

It'll show you the current version and a list of commands you can use if the installation was successful.

[Original source](https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/5987693)

Answer (score -1):

If you don’t have a brew on your Mac.
First, install the brew using the terminal.
Enter the code below and hit enter

/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

After installed brew

Type

> php -v

to check the PHP version if PHP is not enabled it shows

zsh command not found php

The next step for checking the PHP is to enter the below command in the terminal

> Sudo vi /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

After running completely check the blow line is shown in the listed line

#PHP was deprecated in macOS 11 and removed from macOS 12

If you find this line is shown or you don’t have php then enter the command below in the terminal

> brew install php

If you already have PHP installed or run the above command successfully, enter the command in the terminal below.

> brew services start php

Then it shows successfully started php.

Next, check the PHP version by entering the command in the terminal.

> php -v

It shows the PHP version installed on your Mac

reference link : https://medium.com/@nadine.fisch/add-php-to-apache-on-macos-12-e3bb43469195

Comment: Please share more details. Why should installing brew be neccessary after all if MAMP is already installed?